# OpenJDK 12 vs commercial JDK 12 : libraries not loading

Tags: java, dll, shared-libraries

I use Netbeans 11.1 and I ran the code from down here on the commercial JDK12 downloaded from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlanywhere:Host=192.168.88.100:3639;ServerName=premier;DatabaseName=smur";
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "*******", "******")) {
            String query = "select * from test";
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt(1);
                    String denumire = rs.getString(2);
                    System.out.println(id + " " + denumire);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected exception : " + sqe.toString() + ", sqlstate = " + sqe.getSQLState());
        Logger.getLogger(SybaseTest64Bit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqe);
    }
}
```

The test is fine, the app connects to the database and retrieves the data.
But then I switched to OpenJDK12 and the app is no longer working, the error is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver"

The same problem appears on OpenJDK 11.
The application users a JAR driver and a few DLLs to connect to this database and I think that OpenJDK does something different and can't find these libraries.
The class IDriver is definitely  included in the JAR as you can see in the image.
[image]

Thank you.

LATER EDIT: full stack is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:555)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:674)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
at sybasetest64bit.SybaseTest64Bit.main(SybaseTest64Bit.java:12)
```

At SybaseTest64Bit.java:12 I have:

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "*******", "******")) {

Full project is here: http://cc123.caido.ro/SybaseTest64Bit.zip

Comment: What's the full stacktrace and the root cause?

Comment: I edited the original post and added the full stack

Comment: The `IDriver` isn't your problem, it's found allright, but it couldn't be initialized. This is most likely due to the native libraries being in the wrong place or otherwise problematic.

Comment: Ok, but why OpenJDK fails where commercial JDK is not? I also added a link to the full project. DLLs are in the same place on both platforms.

Comment: Find out why the native libraries can't be loaded, whether it's a location issue or something else.

Comment: If I would know how to do this I wouldn't write here. I tried to run the Netbeans debugger but no extra info was provided. I started the project with "-verbose:jni" option but this new output was also not very helpful.

Comment: Well I'm not holding out on you, if I knew what your problem is I'd tell you. The native library is the root cause, that much I can remote debug for you. Google around for some help.

Comment: :) There's not much info about this online as Sybase is not the most popular database. Anyway, I would say that there is some problem in OpenJDK that triggers the problem because commercial JDK12 works fine.

Comment: I doubt it's Sybase specific. Also it's no use blaming that "OpenJDK is wrong", especially considering that the official JDK is based on the OpenJDK. The problem is with the native library, not OpenJDK. You should be Googling how to debug problems with native libraries if you want to solve this.